# How to keep the (stripe) pattern in the legend when saving a plot (R-ggplot-ggpattern)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpattern

I am not able to save the chart as an image (png or other) keeping the **stripe **pattern in the legend. Dot patterns and others work, but not stripes. Could anyone give me some advice?
Thanks in advance for your help

My sample problem

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

data <- data.frame(OBS_VALUE = rnorm(12, 10),
                   COUNTRY = c(rep(c("Flat"), times=6), rep(c("House"), times=6)),
                   SERIES_NAME = rep(c(rep(c("price"), times=3), rep(c("cost"), times=3)), times=2),
                   OBS_DATE = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01"), "years"), times=4)
)

chart = data %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=OBS_DATE, y=OBS_VALUE)) +
  geom_col_pattern( 
    aes(pattern = SERIES_NAME),
    position = position_dodge(),
    fill            = 'red',
    colour          = 'red', 
    pattern_density = 0.5, 
    pattern_fill    = 'white',
    pattern_colour  = 'white'
  )+
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(price = "stripe", cost = "circle")) +
  facet_grid(~COUNTRY)
  


ggsave(
  "chart_test.png" ,
  plot = chart,
  scale = 1,
  width = 20,
  height = 10,
  units = "cm",
  dpi=320
)
```

And the chart appears like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is the combination of scale and width and height which do not fit:
Try a scale < 1 or adapt width / height:

```
ggsave(
  "chart_test.png" ,
  plot = chart,
  scale = 0.9,
  width = 20,
  height = 10,
  units = "cm",
  dpi=320
)
```

[image]